# Issue with conditions in while loop in C language. || doesn't fit?

Tags: c, while-loop, multiple-conditions

I'm wondering why 0 or -20 doesn't end loop. Hope you will help me guys because I'm stuck lil bit:(

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int days;
   printf("Please insert number of days: ");
   scanf("%d", &days);

   while(days != 0 || days != -20)
    {
      printf("%d days are %d week(s) and %d day(s). (0 or - 20 to quit)",
               days, days/7, days%7 );
      scanf("%d", &days);
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just think about the logic flow when `days == 0`.

Comment: `days != 0 || days != -20` If days is different then 0 or days is different then 20. It's always true, all possible numbers are different then zero and zero is different then 20.

Comment: Almost like you need to rethink the conjunction...

Comment: Got it thank you boyz

Comment: @stalker.exe please "accept" the best answer that solves your problem, when you are able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
while(days != 0 || days != -20)//will never exit loop, because days cannot be
                               //both -20 and 0 at the same time.
```

to

```
while(days != 0 && days != -20) // if one or the other is false, loop will exit.
                                // i.e. True && False == 1 && 0 == false -> exit loop
```

To get the behavior you are expecting.

But It can also be expressed:

```
while(days <= 0 && days >= -20)
```

To provide a range of days that will allow you to stay in loop, and a range for which the loop will exit.

Comment: Thanks now i will remeber

Answer (score 1):

The expression:

```
days != 0 || days != -20
```

will always be true because no matter what the value of `days`, it will either not be equal to `0` ***OR*** it will not be equal to `-20` (and maybe both).

You want the expression to be true only when `days` is not equal to either. That is, true if it is not equal to `0` ***AND*** it is not equal to `-20`.

So just replace the OR operator (||) with the AND operator (&&).

```
while(days != 0 && days != -20)
{
}
```

This causes the loop to repeat as long as both sub expressions are true.

Comment: Thank you very very much